# System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'SALESDBEntities' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is quite confusing.

I have a solution with a main project and a class library. All of my DbContexts are inside the class library. I manually copy the connection strings for the contexts from the class library to the main project. I used this setup for many projects without issue, except for one project.

app.config for Class Library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Common_Code.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SALESDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Sales_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Sales_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Sales_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SALESDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DESIGNDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Design_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Design_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Design_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DESIGNDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PRODDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Manufacturing.Manufacturing_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Manufacturing.Manufacturing_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Manufacturing.Manufacturing_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PRODDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="QCDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.QC_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.QC_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.QC_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=S612SRVR1\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=QCDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

app.config for Main Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Common_Code.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SALESDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Sales_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Sales_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Sales_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SALESDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DESIGNDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Design_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Design_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Design_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DESIGNDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="PRODDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Manufacturing.Manufacturing_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Manufacturing.Manufacturing_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.Manufacturing.Manufacturing_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=server2\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=PRODDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="QCDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.QC_Data.csdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.QC_Data.ssdl|res://CommonCode/Datasets.Contexts.QC_Data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=S612SRVR1\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=QCDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

They are quite literally identical.

According to my nLog the exception I'm getting is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'SALESDBEntities' could be found in the application config file.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this exception keeps happening in this project. Both connection strings are exactly the same and work on other projects referencing this same class library.

Comment: What kind of application is the main project?

Comment: Just a standard C# WPF application.

Comment: Well I don't really have any ideas. Check that the config file does indeed contain the connection string when it's running, maybe something happens during the build that messes things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my own problem.

I noticed that the `app.config` and `appname.exe.config` files were not the same size and did not contain the same content.

I had to clear the `bin/Debug` and `obj/Debug` directories for the files to finally match.